# How to get result for one millisecond differences in cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, cql

For Example cqlsh query:

```
 select * from table where eventtime >= '2015-06-02 06:30:00+0530' and eventtime <= '2015-06-02 09:30:00+0530';
```

output is comming 4 rows.
but in case of change the

```
 eventtime >'2015-06-02 06:30:00+0530' and eventtime <= '2015-06-02 09:30:00+0530';
```

also getting same result(4 rows).
but i need 3 rows.  where eventtime type is "timestamp"

Answer (score 3):

The internal storage of timestamp has millisecond precision, which isn't shown by default.  See more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547616/cassandra-cqlsh-how-to-show-microseconds-milliseconds-for-timestamp-columns) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32151887/why-does-this-cql-return-empty-results-with-beginning-and-ending-date-range-are/32155376#32155376).